# Inner HTML Parse JSON to HTML a tag not working proprely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an url where I am trying to get the data and using Jquery inner html I am trying to display the url present in the json as a tag in html

code

```
<script>    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://cybersecurity.apievangelist.com/apis/news/ ',
      type: 'GET' // this is default, but worth pointing out
    }).done(function(data){
      var objone = JSON.parse(data);
          for (i in objone) {
                $('#myContent').append("<div class='well'><a href= " + objone[i].url + ">" + objone[i].title +"</a><br /></div>");
          }
    });

</script>

<div class="container" id="myContent">
</div>
```

for some objects in json the a tags are working properly for some the a tag is not woking

OutPut
[image]

I have done the inspect 
 for the objects where a tag is not working properly
 the a tag the data where it should be inside the a tag is being printed outside

Please help me as how to get this corrected. Thanks advance !!

[image]

Comment: That would be caused by attempting to append invalid HTML. Could you please `console.log` a string you're attempting to append which does not work so we can see exactly what the values are. I would guess there's some issues with the quotes.

Comment: There is no issue with the string quotes cause its a properly structured JSON. I have checked that

Comment: Its with the </a> tag ... "Swagger with WSO2 API Manager" is outside </a> tag where-else the other one in the Picture namely "Why you should treat..." is inside </a> tag.

Comment: Try `$('#myContent').append("<div class='well'><a href= '" + objone[i].url + "'>" + objone[i].title +"</a><br /></div>");`

Answer (score 3):

It works for me by just adding single quote between the href value. Like this:

```
$('#myContent').append("<div class='well'><a href='" + objone[i].url + "'>" + objone[i].title +"</a><br /></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, `I can see few strings are coming in between Anchor tags, but few strings are coming after anchor tag.`

For example the first one from your screenshot `Swagger with WSO2` is coming after the closed anchor tag but `Why you should your API....` is coming in between anchor tags. So you should follow the same standard for everything heading should come in between anchor tags so everything behaves same.

Comment: I get it thats an api where the data is coming it is a valid json, I know thats the problem.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. You're just describing the symptoms of the issue, which the OP is well aware of already.

Comment: If you want to manually parse the text and make it as a link, you can parse the html attribute and take the text. use DOMParser(), 

   const parser = new DOMParser();
    const parsedHTML = parser.parseFromString(link, 'text/html');
    const emojies: any = parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('div.well'); and then create a anchor tag and you can replace it there.